# Use Variable and String in ansible.builtin.combine

Tags: ansible

I have got a YAML file that uses the following structure:

```
crdb:
  db:
    - test
  users:
    - id: 42712
      permissions:
        - level: ALL
          db: test
```

Currently I am building a Dictionary by doing the following:

```
- set_fact:
    db_user_permissions: "{{ db_user_permissions | default ({}) | combine({ item.key: item.value }) }}"
  loop: "{{ crdb.users | json_query('[*].{key: id, value: permissions}')}}"
  when: item.value
```

This results in an output that looks like this:

```
{"db_user_permissions": {"42712": [{"db": "test", "level": "ALL"}], "42699": [{"db": "test", "level": "ALL"}]}
```

However I have noticed that if I have duplicate keys (in this case IDs) then only the last one gets used in the final Dictionary.

One possible solution I had to this is to have the key for the Dictionary be a combination of the ID and the DB, however I cannot make this work.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
- set_fact:
    db_user_permissions: "{{ db_user_permissions | default ({}) | combine({ item.key_item.value[0].db : item.value }) }}"
  loop: "{{ crdb.users | json_query('[*].{key: id, value: permissions}')}}"
  when: item.value
```

```
- set_fact:
    db_user_permissions: "{{ db_user_permissions | default ({}) | combine({ {{ item.key }}_{{ item.value[0].db }} : item.value }) }}"
  loop: "{{ crdb.users | json_query('[*].{key: id, value: permissions}')}}"
  when: item.value
```

```
- set_fact:
    db_user_permissions: "{{ db_user_permissions | default ({}) | combine({ item.key'_'item.value[0].db : item.value }) }}"
  loop: "{{ crdb.users | json_query('[*].{key: id, value: permissions}')}}"
  when: item.value
```

Is there a correct way to achieve something like this?

Comment: In a general (so not dealing with duplicate id) setting, what you are doing is overly complicated for what you want to achieve and can be done via simply via `crdb.users | items2dict(key_name='id', value_name='permissions')`. It will result in the same as you are facing, though, as dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the resulting dictionary though? And if your YAML file is structured like that, why not restructure it instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"If I have duplicate keys (in this case IDs) then only the last one gets used in the final dictionary"***

A: Use the Jinja filter [groupby](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby) or Ansible filter [community.general.lists_mergeby](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/lists_mergeby_filter.html). For example, given the below data for testing of the duplicate *id*

```yaml
  crdb:
    db: [test]
    users:
    - id: 42712
      permissions:
      - {db: test, level: ALL}
    - id: 42699
      permissions:
      - {db: test, level: ALL}
    - id: 42699
      permissions:
      - {db: test_X, level: X}
```

1. **The filter groupby**

You don't have to iterate the list of the users. Instead, group the result of the *json_query* by the *key*

```yaml
  crdb_groupby: "{{ crdb.users|
                    json_query('[*].{key: id, value: permissions}')|
                    groupby('key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  crdb_groupby:
    - - 42699
      - - key: 42699
          value:
          - {db: test, level: ALL}
        - key: 42699
          value:
          - {db: test_X, level: X}
    - - 42712
      - - key: 42712
          value:
          - {db: test, level: ALL}
```

Now, select any structure you want. For example,

```yaml
  db_user_permissions: "{{ dict(crdb_groupby|map('first')|
                                zip(crdb_groupby|map('last')|
                                                 map('map', attribute='value')|
                                                 map('flatten'))) }}"
```

gives the dictionary

```yaml
  db_user_permissions:
    42699:
    - {db: test, level: ALL}
    - {db: test_X, level: X}
    42712:
    - {db: test, level: ALL}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    crdb:
      db: [test]
      users:
        - id: 42712
          permissions:
            - {db: test, level: ALL}
        - id: 42699
          permissions:
            - {db: test, level: ALL}
        - id: 42699
          permissions:
            - {db: test_X, level: X}

    crdb_groupby: "{{ crdb.users|
                      json_query('[*].{key: id, value: permissions}')|
                      groupby('key') }}"
    db_user_permissions: "{{ dict(crdb_groupby|map('first')|
                                  zip(crdb_groupby|map('last')|
                                                   map('map', attribute='value')|
                                                   map('flatten'))) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: crdb|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: crdb_groupby|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: db_user_permissions|to_yaml
```

---

2. **The filter [community.general.lists_mergeby](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_merging_lists_of_dictionaries.html)**

Usage of this filter is simpler

```yaml
  db_list: "{{ [crdb.users, []]|
               community.general.lists_mergeby('id',
                                               recursive=True,
                                               list_merge='append') }}"
```

gives the list

```yaml
  db_list:
    - id: 42699
      permissions:
      - {db: test, level: ALL}
      - {db: test_X, level: X}
    - id: 42712
      permissions:
      - {db: test, level: ALL}
```

If you add the filter *tems2dict* to the pipe

```yaml
  db_dict: "{{ [crdb.users, []]|
               community.general.lists_mergeby('id',
                                               recursive=True,
                                               list_merge='append')|
               items2dict(key_name='id',
                          value_name='permissions') }}"
```

you'll get the same result

```yaml
  db_dict:
    42699:
    - {db: test, level: ALL}
    - {db: test_X, level: X}
    42712:
    - {db: test, level: ALL}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    crdb:
      db: [test]
      users:
        - id: 42712
          permissions:
            - {db: test, level: ALL}
        - id: 42699
          permissions:
            - {db: test, level: ALL}
        - id: 42699
          permissions:
            - {db: test_X, level: X}

    db_list: "{{ [crdb.users, []]|
                 community.general.lists_mergeby('id',
                                                 recursive=True,
                                                 list_merge='append') }}"
    db_dict: "{{ [crdb.users, []]|
                 community.general.lists_mergeby('id',
                                                 recursive=True,
                                                 list_merge='append')|
                 items2dict(key_name='id',
                            value_name='permissions') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: db_list|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: db_dict|to_yaml
```

---

Note: The filter [community.general.lists_mergeby](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_merging_lists_of_dictionaries.html) calls the filter *combine*. The functionality of the parameters is exactly the same as in the filter [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries).